# instanceof is returning false when the value is actually an instance

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to check what instance is being used?

I am logging this to the console:

```js
import { OrthographicCamera } from 'three';

// Later in the file:

console.log(camera instanceof OrthographicCamera, camera);
```

and It outputs `false`, but when I log the value of `camera` to the console, I get this:

[image: Proof of OrthographicCamera]

I am not sure why it is showing that the camera isn't an instance, so is there a way to get more information as to what it is actually looking at?

Here is where the camera is created:

```
export function Camera(options?: CameraOptions) {
  return function (target: new () => object) {
    return class GameCamera extends target {
      readonly camera!: Camera;  
      constructor() {
        super();
        const dim = this.cameraDimensions();

        // create the Three camera
        this.camera = new OrthographicCamera(dim.left, dim.right, dim.top, dim.bottom, options?.near ?? 0, options?.far ?? 100);
      }
    }
  }
}}
```

The camera gets created in the Decorator and added to the `gameObjects` array. Then when I get the `activeCamera` it is a reference to the above decorator that extends `target`.

Here is where I am doing the `instanceof` lookup:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class Camera {
  get activeCamera() {
    return Engine.activeCamera;
  }

  mouseToWorldPoint(mousePoint: Vector3) {
    if (this.activeCamera) {
      // Here is the check:
      console.log(camera instanceof OrthographicCamera, camera);
    }
  }
}
```

This is how I get the camera:

```js
export class Engine {
  static gameObjects: GameObject[] = [];
  static get activeCamera() {
    return this.gameObjects.find(i => i.gameObjectType === 'camera' && i.isActive === true) as GameCamera | undefined;
  };
}
```

I have broken the project up into multiple npm workspaces:

```json
{
  "name": "game-engine",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run start --workspace=test"
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "test",
    "packages/core",
    "packages/common",
    "packages/input",
    "packages/objects"
  ]
}
```

2 of the workspaces get information from the three module.

- class `GameCamera` is apart of the `packages/objects` module (creates the camera).
- class `Camera` is apart of the `packages/common` module (checks for instance).

**Note:** This been working like this for some time and just seems to have started happening.

Comment: What does `console.log(camera instanceof OrthographicCamera);` output?

Comment: It outputs `false`

Comment: How are you creating the camera? With `const camera = new OrthographicCamera();` it outputs `true`. See the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-rgb-g7i6x4?file=/src/index.js:134-168)

Comment: I am creating a camera in a decorator. `return class GameCamera extends target` then later I check for the instance in a service. I'll provide an update.

Comment: I don't know if this is a threejs bug or not, but in the console I am seeing: WARNING: Multiple instances of Three.js being imported. But I don't see multiple insances.

Comment: that might also be the issue, if two different three.js instances exist then you may be checking it three.js A's `OrthographicCamera` instance is an instance of three.js B's `OrthographicCamera`, which will always be false

Comment: In there docs it says you can do this: `/* Option 2: Import just the parts you need. */
import { Scene } from 'three';

const scene = new Scene();` which is how I am importing everything https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Installation

Comment: I don't know if this would cause any issues, but I broke the project up into (currently) 4 different npm projects using `workspaces` and one main project.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn that's your issue. Monorepos (what you're describing) generally have two types of code: apps and packages. Apps contain application code, and packages contain code for stuff that is shared (such as an instance of a library). If you don't share the instance between your code, you have multiple instances, which leads to bugs like this. You should have a package that just handles `three` and exports everything you'll need in the other packages/apps. See an sort of example here https://github.com/t3-oss/create-t3-turbo and how the package "db" contains the prisma code

Comment: @Samathingamajig Moving the two into the same module fixed it, now I just need to figure how I want to handle that globally. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix my issue what I did is in the `packages/core` package I added an export to export threejs

**index.ts (@engine/core)**

```js
import * as Three from 'three';
export { Three };
```

Then when I need to use threejs in another package I just use the one in core like this:

**@engine/objects/something.ts**

```js
import { Three } from '@engine/core';

export class CreateObject {
  constructor(){
    this.obj = new Three.Object3D();
  }
}
```